# How to make an environment variable (cern root) permanently?

Tags: 18.04, environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux, paths

I am pretty new with Ubuntu as the Windows subsystem. I've been trying to run [the ROOT data analysis framework](https://root.cern.ch/) (change its path to make it available permanently) but for some reason is not working as it should. Any help will be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [here](https://root.cern/install/) states that the following command will set up your environment:

```
source root/bin/thisroot.sh
```

> To avoid having to source thisroot.sh every time one needs to use
> ROOT, it is typical to add the instruction to .bashrc, .profile or
> analogous configuration files. Note, however, that sourcing
> thisroot.sh might interfere with ROOT versions installed with
> different methods.

Edit the existing `.bashrc` file in your home directory with an editor such as `vim` or `nano`, and add the line shown above at the end of the file to source the environment file. Be sure that the path to the `thisroot.sh` file is correct for your installation. After doing this, logout of the system. Subsequent logins will run the `thisroot.sh` file automatically without manual intervention.